# Excel VBA to select every two cells out of a large range

Tags: vba, excel, merge

Trying to merge every 2 cells out of a large range. My range of cells is B2:ABC2 currently but will be more before too long (each day of the year). I am looking to merge every two cells so B2&C2 will be merged, D2&E2 will be merged and so on. Is there an easy way to code this to select every two cells from the range and merge them? Everytime I've played with it it just seems to merge the whole range into one.

Comment: Can you show us the code that isn't working? It's sometimes easier for us to suggest a fix than to write the whole thing out from scratch

Comment: Best to show the code you tried.  A basic For loop with Step 2 should work.

Comment: @CallumDA doh; started typing before comments showed up... yes, this is a collaboration site, not code-for-you!

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could use a step for this, with For.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim LC as Long

LC = Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 to LC Step 2
    Range(Cells(1,i),Cells(1,i+1)).Merge
Next i
```

Didn't test, just gave it a whirl.